# How do I launch a exe file (will pop out GUI) with windows service correctly

Tags: user-interface, windows-services, exe, createprocessasuser

I have a problem with launching a exe file with windows service.

My service will call "CreateProcessasUser" function in MSDN, and it will launch the exe file correctly, however the launched exe task only shows in task manager but didn't prompt on desktop(GUI).
Is there any ideas to fix this problem?

Thanks a lot!!!